# Schengen visa for Spain and France

Tags: visas, schengen, france, spain

I am planning a 10-day visit to France and Spain. We will be visiting Paris first and then Barcelona and then Madrid.

Which country should we apply for the visa? Our entry point is Paris and we are planning to stay 6 days in Spain.

Answer (score 2):

With a 10 day trip and 6 days in Spain, you'll be in France for 4 days. As 6 is larger than 4 that means Spain is the main destination for your trip and the country that you should apply to for a visa.